# imagefill() in my php code shows an Fatal error : Out of memory (allocated 10485760) (tried to allocate 8275105 bytes)

Tags: php, image-processing

I have an error in the below php file, QR1_generator.php.

```php
function labeling ($item_code,$product_version,$supplyer_code,$batch_date,$prog_numb, $folder)  
{   
        
    $mm_w = 55;
    $mm_h = 30;
    $dpi = 900;
    $width = $mm_w *$dpi/25.4;
    $height = $mm_h *$dpi/25.4;
    $margin = 20;
    $w_real = $width-$margin;
    $h_real = $height-$margin;  
    $res = 0.7;
    $margin_line = 200;
    $layers = array();
    //$layers[] = "frame.png";
    $layers[] = "./phpqrcode/img/logo_avensys_label.png";
    $image = null;
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imageresolution($image, $dpi);
    // to make background transparent
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    $transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparency);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    //if you want to set background color
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    echo $width . " " . $height . " " . $transparency;
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
    imagesetthickness($image, 5);
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($layers); $i++) 
    {
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($layers[$i]);
        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
        if ($w_real/$h_real*$res > $ratio_orig)
        {
            $nwidth = $h_real*$ratio_orig*$res ;
            $nheight = $h_real*$res ;
        } else {
            $nheight = $w_real/$ratio_orig*$res ;
            $nwidth = $w_real*$res ;
        }
        imagecopyresampled($image, imagecreatefrompng($layers[$i]), ($width - $nwidth)/2, 0, 0, 0, $nwidth, $nheight, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    }

    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    imageroundedrectangle($image , $margin, $margin , $w_real , $h_real , 50, $black );
    imageline($image,$margin_line,$nheight + $margin,$width-$margin_line,$nheight + $margin,$black);
    $mm_w = 40;
    $mm_h = 10;
    $dpi = 900;
    $recwidth = $mm_w *$dpi/25.4;
    $recheight = $mm_h *$dpi/25.4;
    $margin_rec = 20;
    $recw_real = $recwidth-2*$margin_rec;
    $rech_real = $recheight-2*$margin_rec;
    $resqr = 1;
    imagesetthickness($image, 2);
    imagerectangle($image, ($width - $recwidth)/2, $nheight + 6*$margin, ($width - $recwidth)/2+$recwidth, $nheight + 6*$margin + $recheight, $black);
    $qr=strtoupper ("$item_code|$product_version|$supplyer_code|$batch_date$prog_numb"); 
    $result_qr_content_in_base64 =  avqr_generator($qr);
    $qr = base64_decode($result_qr_content_in_base64);
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesizefromstring($qr);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($qr);
    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
    if ($recw_real/$rech_real*$resqr > $ratio_orig)
    {
        $nqrwidth = $rech_real*$ratio_orig*$resqr;
        $nqrheight = $rech_real*$resqr ;
    }else {
        $nqrheight = $recw_real/$ratio_orig*$resqr;
        $nqrwidth = $recw_real*$resqr ;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($image, $im, ($width - $recw_real)/2, $nheight + 6 * $margin + $margin, 0, 0, $nqrwidth, $nqrheight, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    $text = strtoupper($item_code.'|'.$product_version.'|'.$supplyer_code.'|'.$batch_date.$prog_numb);
    $arr = explode('|', $text);
    $text1 = $arr[0];
    $text2 = implode('|',array_slice($arr, 1, 3));
    $textdim = 70;
    $font = __DIR__ .'./arial.ttf';
    list($x, $y) = ImageTTFCenter($im, $text1, $font, $textdim ,0);
    // Scrivo il testo sull'immagine
    //imagettftext($image, $textdim, 0, ($width - $recw_real)/2+$nqrwidth + $margin_rec+100, 720, $black, $font, $text1);
    imagettftext($image, $textdim, 0, $x+1070, $y+565, $black, $font, $text1);
    list($x, $y) = ImageTTFCenter($im, $text2, $font, $textdim ,0);
    //imagettftext($image, $textdim, 0, ($width - $recw_real)/2+$nqrwidth + $margin_rec+100, 720+$textdim+2*$margin_rec, $black, $font, $text2);
    imagettftext($image, $textdim, 0, $x+1070, $y+565+$textdim+2*$margin_rec, $black, $font, $text2);
    imagettftext($image, 90, 0, 407+$nqrwidth/2, 810-$nqrheight/2, $black, $font, 'Q1');
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagepng($image, $folder.'./QR1_label/'.$item_code.'_complete_'.$prog_numb.'.png');
    $img2 = imagecrop($image, ['x' => ($width - $recwidth)/2, 'y' => $nheight + 6*$margin, 'width' => $recwidth+2, 'height' => $recheight+2]);
    imagepng($img2, $folder.'./QR1_label/'.$item_code.'_compact_'.$prog_numb.'.png');
    sleep(1);
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($img2);
    $image = null;
    $img2 = null;
    unset($img2);
    unset($image);
    unset($im);
    unset($qr);
    
}
```

while invoking this function 10+ times, I got the error like

> Fatal error : Out of memory (allocated 16777216) (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in ... "

The errors are coming from the lines below:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagepng($image, $folder.'./QR1_label/'.$item_code.'_complete_'.$prog_numb.'.png');
```

[image]

To resolve this issue, I set the memory_limit in php.ini file as 4000M.
When I restart apache, I don't see this error. But I call this function 10+, or 100+ times, it shows errors like above.

What else should I handle with?

Comment: In my experience, it is usually pretty rare that changing your memory limit will fix OOM issues, it is almost always a symptom of something else. To your code, it is hard to determine which line is raising that error since the line numbers don't match and you've got other code you are calling which isn't posted. However, my recommendation would be to break this large function into several smaller functions that do only portions. You should be able to test each to determine if you reach a memory limit then.

Comment: SO examine what is going on in your for loop, if you look you are adding to an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly the function doesn't return anything or invoke any globals, though. Either there is some other code that OP is not showing that is accumulating data in memory, or they are somehow outrunning PHP's garbage collector. _As a test_ [which will tank your performance] try adding `gc_collect_cycles()` to the loop that is invoking this function. If the problem goes away, then you need to tweak the GC settings to be more aggressive. If not, then the problem is something else you've not shown to us.

Comment: It should also be noted that for OOM errors the line listed in the error message is not necessarily "the culprit", it's just where PHP finally ran out of memory to allocate. The straw that broke the camel's back. Frequently there's a completely unrelated bit of code loading stacks of bricks on the camel elsewhere.

Comment: I am considering the reason might be low capability of the server. My current server has 4GB of RAM, 2 CPUs. Furthermore, in the same server, I have actual running services using Apache. Would it be a reason? Now I am moving the server to AWS EC2.